# Как при выборе файла через input file выводилось его расширение и где он используется?

Tags: javascript, input, shortcode

Основная проблема заключается в том что я не нахожу иных решений кроме сделать это все через конструкцию if else, но в таком случаи код выйдет чрезвычайно длинным.[image: Что то на подобии такого]

есть ли иные решения?

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Сделай объект с ключами (расширения) и нужными значениями. Если такого ключа в объекте нет - бери значение по умолчанию...